# Please update to the latest Node LTS version." Get this type of error, but if i update also get error not supported

Tags: node.js

Error before update:
"D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd>ionic cordova platform add android
ERR: Your Node.js version is v10.23.3. Node.js 10 reached end-of-life on 2021-04-30 and is no longer supported. Please update to the latest Node LTS version."
Error after update:
"
D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd>npm run-script build

> teentalks@2.1.0 build
> ng build

10% building 4/5 modules 1 active ...odules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\es5-polyfills.jsnode:internal/crypto/hash:69
this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
at module.exports (D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
at D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
at D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19
at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:46:13)
at processResource (D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
at iteratePitchingLoaders (D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
at runLoaders (D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
at NormalModule.doBuild (D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3)
at NormalModule.build (D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:446:15)
at Compilation.buildModule (D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
at D:\Trio-Downloads\Teen Talk code\Code\StepUp-Mobile-App-FrontEnd\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:981:14 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v20.4.0"

Install the android platform supported to used versions.
→ ionic cordova platform add android@9.0.0

Get production build using cmd → npm run build --prod

After that take a android build → ionic cordova build android
expected to run this command after above cmd and Once the build completed your are getting an apk file.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).